# Python and lambda functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Might seems like a nooby question (myabe it is), but why does python behave like that:

```
>>>a = []
>>>for i in xrange(5):
...    a.append(lambda: i + 1)

>>>a[0]()
5
>>>a[1]()
5
>>>a[2]()
5
>>>a[3]()
5
>>>a[4]()
5
```

when there are different functions stored in a:

```
>>aaa
[<function <lambda> at 0x100499d70>, <function <lambda> at 0x100499e60>, <function <lambda> at 0x100499ed8>, <function <lambda> at 0x100499de8>, <function <lambda> at 0x10049f050>]
```

or have I missed something really important in python docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the closure is built on the value of `i` which ends up as `4`.

if you want to keep `i` inside lambda you can use default variables.

```
>>>for i in xrange(5):
...    a.append(lambda x=i: x + 1)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. All in all I was right about missing something important (time of execution and name spacing). Default arguments do store value in function name space. Thanks!